# Problems working with files runtime in executable jar

Tags: java, file-io, jar, runtime, executable

I have a working code (at least in eclipse), in which I work with some files: I have a .dot file I write into some text, so I can read it to create a graph. Then I save the graph into a .png image, which I display on a frame..

My problem is: In the executable .jar file I can´t acces these files, and also - if i know it right - I can´t even change em runtime. So I tried to work with Streams. I can access the .dot file like:

```
$InputStream fileStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/graf.dot");$
```

But I have no clue how can i write into it. I found *OutputStreamWriter*, but it also requires a path, which I can´t acces like I accessed the InputStream..I also struggle with reading the text from the file and creating the .png file... Can you please help me? Is it even possible to work with these files at runtime?

I had the same problem accessing the background image of the frame, but I found a solution:

```java
$URL bgPath = this.getClass().getResource("/background.jpg");
panel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bgPath));$
```

So I really hope there exists some similar solution for the files I work with..

```java
private void createGraph() throws IOException { 
    /* Creating the graph into "graf.dot" file.
     * The format is in DOT language.
     */
    String fileName = "src/main/resources/graf.dot";
    InputStream fileStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/graf.dot");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileStream));
    /* Here I write the content into *graph_string**/
    br.close();
    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
        //FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName);
        writer.write(graph_string);
        writer.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error writing into file");
    }finally {
        drawGraph();            
    }
}

private void drawGraph() throws IOException {   
    /*
     * Reading the graph from file for visualization
     */
    String fileName = "src/main/resources/graf.dot";
    InputStream fileStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/graf.dot");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileStream));      
    File file = new File("src/main/resources/graf.dot");
    String str="";
    try {
       str = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Errorrr reading from file.");
    }
    MutableGraph g = Parser.read(str);  
    Graphviz.fromGraph(g).render(
            Format.PNG).toFile(new File("src/main/resources/graph.png"));
    BufferedImage background = ImageIO.read(new File("src/main/resources/graph.png"));
    panel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(background));          
...
}
```

Comment: Normally it is not possible for a program to write into its own jar file.

Comment: **EDIT:** I eliminated the .dot file from the code I am only passing a String to access the graph. Now I can save and display the .png file without any errors. Thank you for your answer, @NormR!